# How to rebuild a binary after installing new packages

Tags: package-management, software-installation, compiling

I installed LAMMPS binaries using cmake from the downloaded tarball. However, I forgot to include the packages. I later installed them via

```
make yes-all
```

After which I rebuild it via :

```
cmake ../cmake
make
```

However after it built, it still shows no additional packages installed. I think I have skipped a nessecary step to rebuild the binary after installing a new package. I tried looking at LAMMPS and Ubuntu forums but didn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Eight months late, but I believe your problem is mixing cmake and make. The warning [here](https://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Build_package.html) elaborates on this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, while this link might answer the question, it's better to include essential parts here.